# ORA-00917: missing comma error

Tags: oracle, insert

Below is my query in ORACLE which is getting `ORA-00917: missing comma` error.

```
INSERT INTO user_account_statement(
   statement_id,
   session_key,
   login_id,
   user_id,
   account_number,
   from_date,
   to_date,
   ipaddress,
   create_date_time
) 
VALUES(1070,
      'fe79e0345986b5a439c26f731234868b53f877366f529',
      '2335',
      '204254',
      '108142',
       to_date('2014-08-18','yyyy-mm-dd'),
       to_date('2014-08-23','yyyy-mm-dd'),
       '106.79.126.249',
       to_date('2014-08-23 16:45:06','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss');
```

I don't know where it requires comma now.

Comment: No comma is required. You are simply missing closing parenthesis for the `value` clause.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Looks like there is a missing `)` at the end :

```
INSERT INTO user_account_statement(statement_id,session_key,login_id,user_id,
        account_number,from_date,to_date,ipaddress,create_date_time)
   VALUES(1070,'fe79e0345986b5a439c26f731234868b53f877366f529','2335','204254','108142',
          to_date('2014-08-18','yyyy-mm-dd'),to_date('2014-08-23','yyyy-mm-dd'),
                  '106.79.126.249',to_date('2014-08-23 16:45:06','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));
```

Comment: Ohh..how dumb i am...!! thanks a lot @Ipg.

Comment: It worked...sometimes it is very difficult to find some small gaps in our code.

Comment: i just logged in to vote up.